# Pemnanently caching results of a Dockerfile command for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on containerizing my Rails app with Docker. I'm frequently rebuilding the app image as I go. One issue I'm running into is my app's dependencies which are installed via `bundle`. Each time the bundle layer is invalidated, the dependencies need to be fetched and since they sum up to a few hundred megs that's less than ideal. There are a number of references to storing the bundle data in a volume ([link](http://bradgessler.com/articles/docker-bundler/)) but I can't seem to make it work. In fact, I dont understand how it will ever work since the bundle container is not yet up during the build time of the app container.

My goal for now is to prevent the bundle layer from getting continuously invalidated. I'm fine with refetching the bundle once my Dockerfile stabilizes and I'm ready for production builds.

Comment: "I can't seem to make it work." What do you mean by that?

Comment: @ChrisPeters I expect the data container to cache the results of the bundle operation after the first `docker build`, yet it never is cached.

Comment: Got it. What happens if you run `docker-compose pull` and then `docker-compose build`? Not sure if you've already tried that. Other things you can do to help: share your `docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile`, and commands you've tried running in your question. It's nearly impossible to help you based on your current question.

Comment: Could you post a (possibly simplified) version of your Dockerfile? Are you COPYing the Gemfile as a separate step from the rest of your app?